# Erro ao acessar o controller - spring securiy

Tags: spring, spring-security

Estou achando estranho este erro.

Classe que está informando no console:

```
package br.com.netsoft.configuracao.auth;

import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

public class JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
    private String tokenHeader;

    public JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter(UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
            JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil, String tokenHeader) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.jwtTokenUtil = jwtTokenUtil;
        this.tokenHeader = tokenHeader;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.debug("Autenticação de processamento para '{}'",
                request.getRequestURL());

        String requestHeader = "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIwMjY3OTUwMDYzNiIsImV4cCI6MTUyMzIxNTg5OX0.LIVrSKcVGHdrDRvCuGlWjoZoFd9WSSyoRWDpBH-YWtZoP3HM4YGwyuED0mVItFrKdEDjSEKvxXj1K2EF_6TCVg";

        String username = null;
        String authToken = null;
        if (requestHeader != null && requestHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            authToken = requestHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(authToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                logger.error(
                        "Ocorreu um erro durante a obtenção do nome de usuário do token.",
                        e);
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                logger.warn("O token está expirado e não é mais válido.", e);
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("Não foi possível encontrar a string do portador, irá ignorar o cabeçalho.");
        }

        logger.debug("Verificando a autenticação para o usuário: '{}'",
                username);
        if (username != null
                && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            logger.debug("O contexto de segurança era nulo, autorizando o usuário.");
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService
                    .loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(authToken, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource()
                        .buildDetails(request));
                logger.info(
                        "usuario autorizado:  '{}', definindo contexto de segurança",
                        username);
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
                        authentication);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Error

```
14:45:07,945 INFO  [stdout] (default task-4) Hibernate: select distinct count(distinct (this_.usr_codigo)) as y0_ from fr_usuario this_ where this_.usr_login=?

14:45:07,950 INFO  [stdout] (default task-4) Hibernate: select this_.usr_codigo as usr_codi1_56_4_, this_.CD_LOGIN_MOVIMENTACAO as CD_LOGIN2_56_4_, this_.DS_SITUACAO as DS_SITUA3_56_4_, this_.IP_MOVIMENTACAO as IP_MOVIM4_56_4_, this_.NR_VERSAO as NR_VERSA5_56_4_, this_.ST_REGISTRO as ST_REGIS6_56_4_, this_.TP_OPERACAO as TP_OPERA7_56_4_, this_.TS_MOVIMENTACAO as TS_MOVIM8_56_4_, this_.usr_administrador as usr_admi9_56_4_, this_.usr_dias_expiracao as usr_dia10_56_4_, this_.usr_email as usr_ema11_56_4_, this_.usr_inicio_expiracao as usr_ini12_56_4_, this_.usr_login as usr_log13_56_4_, this_.usr_nome as usr_nom14_56_4_, this_.usr_senha as usr_sen15_56_4_, this_.usr_tipo_expiracao as usr_tip16_56_4_, this_.usr_digital as usr_dig17_56_4_, usuariosgr2_.usr_codigo as usr_cod11_56_6_, usuariosgr2_.ugg_id as ugg_id1_58_6_, usuariosgr2_.ugg_id as ugg_id1_58_0_, usuariosgr2_.CD_LOGIN_MOVIMENTACAO as CD_LOGIN2_58_0_, usuariosgr2_.DS_SITUACAO as DS_SITUA3_58_0_, usuariosgr2_.IP_MOVIMENTACAO as IP_MOVIM4_58_0_, usuariosgr2_.NR_VERSAO as NR_VERSA5_58_0_, usuariosgr2_.ST_REGISTRO as ST_REGIS6_58_0_, usuariosgr2_.TP_OPERACAO as TP_OPERA7_58_0_, usuariosgr2_.TS_MOVIMENTACAO as TS_MOVIM8_58_0_, usuariosgr2_.grp_id as grp_id9_58_0_, usuariosgr2_.sis_id as sis_id10_58_0_, usuariosgr2_.usr_codigo as usr_cod11_58_0_, grupoentit3_.grp_id as grp_id1_53_1_, grupoentit3_.CD_LOGIN_MOVIMENTACAO as CD_LOGIN2_53_1_, grupoentit3_.DS_SITUACAO as DS_SITUA3_53_1_, grupoentit3_.IP_MOVIMENTACAO as IP_MOVIM4_53_1_, grupoentit3_.NR_VERSAO as NR_VERSA5_53_1_, grupoentit3_.ST_REGISTRO as ST_REGIS6_53_1_, grupoentit3_.TP_OPERACAO as TP_OPERA7_53_1_, grupoentit3_.TS_MOVIMENTACAO as TS_MOVIM8_53_1_, grupoentit3_.grp_nome as grp_nome9_53_1_, grupoentit3_.grp_role as grp_rol10_53_1_, grupoentit3_.sis_codigo as sis_cod11_53_1_, sistemaent4_.sis_id as sis_id1_55_2_, sistemaent4_.CD_LOGIN_MOVIMENTACAO as CD_LOGIN2_55_2_, sistemaent4_.DS_SITUACAO as DS_SITUA3_55_2_, sistemaent4_.IP_MOVIMENTACAO as IP_MOVIM4_55_2_, sistemaent4_.NR_VERSAO as NR_VERSA5_55_2_, sistemaent4_.ST_REGISTRO as ST_REGIS6_55_2_, sistemaent4_.TP_OPERACAO as TP_OPERA7_55_2_, sistemaent4_.TS_MOVIMENTACAO as TS_MOVIM8_55_2_, sistemaent4_.sis_descricao as sis_desc9_55_2_, sistemaent4_.sis_sigla as sis_sig10_55_2_, sistemaent5_.sis_id as sis_id1_55_3_, sistemaent5_.CD_LOGIN_MOVIMENTACAO as CD_LOGIN2_55_3_, sistemaent5_.DS_SITUACAO as DS_SITUA3_55_3_, sistemaent5_.IP_MOVIMENTACAO as IP_MOVIM4_55_3_, sistemaent5_.NR_VERSAO as NR_VERSA5_55_3_, sistemaent5_.ST_REGISTRO as ST_REGIS6_55_3_, sistemaent5_.TP_OPERACAO as TP_OPERA7_55_3_, sistemaent5_.TS_MOVIMENTACAO as TS_MOVIM8_55_3_, sistemaent5_.sis_descricao as sis_desc9_55_3_, sistemaent5_.sis_sigla as sis_sig10_55_3_ from fr_usuario this_ left outer join fr_usuario_grupo usuariosgr2_ on this_.usr_codigo=usuariosgr2_.usr_codigo left outer join fr_grupo grupoentit3_ on usuariosgr2_.grp_id=grupoentit3_.grp_id left outer join fr_sistema sistemaent4_ on grupoentit3_.sis_codigo=sistemaent4_.sis_id left outer join fr_sistema sistemaent5_ on usuariosgr2_.sis_id=sistemaent5_.sis_id where this_.usr_login=? limit ?

14:45:07,968 INFO  [br.com.netsoft.configuracao.auth.JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter] (default task-4) usuario autorizado:  '02679500636', definindo contexto de segurança    
14:45:07,971 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-4) UT005023: Exception handling request to /des-if-web/admin/paisRecurso/buscar: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails]: Specified class is an interface
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) [spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at br.com.netsoft.configuracao.auth.JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter.java:94) [classes:]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:248) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:77) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:167) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:761) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails]: Specified class is an interface
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:99) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:142) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:80) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:102) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:160) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        ... 65 more
```

Comment: Erro era porque no controller, estava com dois parâmetros de entrada, sem necessidade.

Não sei como informar que está ok

Comment: Crie uma resposta com o ajuste que foi feito por você e aceite a mesma.